# KeyError: 'customer'

Tags: python, json, flask, python-requests

How can I print out customer email from this json?

How can I access customers  email  in this json using python loop function without getting KeyError?

```
{
   "orders":[
      {
         "created_at":"2020-06-11T07:56:42-04:00",
         "customer":{
            "id":3684055154844,
            "email":"xxxxxxx@gmail.com",
            "accepts_marketing":False,
            "created_at":"2020-06-10T15:51:50-04:00",
            "updated_at":"2020-06-11T07:56:42-04:00",
            "first_name":"xxx",
            "last_name":"xxxxx",
            "orders_count":1,
            "state":"disabled",
            "total_spent":"1160.00",
            "last_order_id":2501429756060,
            "note":"None",
            "verified_email":True,
            "multipass_identifier":"None",
            "tax_exempt":False,
            "phone":"None",
            "tags":"",
            "last_order_name":"#1005",
            "currency":"xxx",
            "accepts_marketing_updated_at":"2020-06-10T15:51:50-04:00",
            "marketing_opt_in_level":"None",
            "admin_graphql_api_id":"gid",
            "default_address":{
               "id":4397679181980,
               "customer_id":3684055154844,
               "first_name":"xxxx",
               "last_name":"xxxxxx",
               "company":"None",
               "address1":"14",
               "address2":"",
               "city":"N",
               "province":"None",
               "country":"K",
               "zip":"0217",
               "phone":"None",
               "name":"J",
               "province_code":"None",
               "country_code":"E",
               "country_name":"K",
               "default":True
            }
         }
      },
```

**my code python loop**

```
        if response.status_code == 200:
            products = json.loads(response.text)
            print(products)

            for order in products['orders']:
                        created_at = order['created_at']
                        customer_total_spent = order['customer']['email']
                        print('order_created_date', created_at)
                        print('customer_email', email)
```

**after running this code i get this error   # customer_orders_count = order['customer']
KeyError: 'customer'**

Comment: What if you add `print(order)` between `created_at =` and `customer_total_spent =`?

Comment: The error mentions a line of code that is not contained in the question, please show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle a situation where your json might not contain the required keys:

You can add a if condition to check the key in your json:

```
for order in products['orders']:
    if 'customer' in order:
        created_at = order['created_at']
        customer_total_spent = order['customer']['email']
        print(customer_total_spent)
        print('order_created_date', created_at)
        print('customer_email', email)
```

OR

You can use get() method to avoid any key error while looping:

```
for order in products['orders']:
    created_at = order.get('created_at', '')
    customer = order.get('customer', '')
    customer_total_spent = customer.get('email', '')
    print(customer_total_spent)
    print('order_created_date', created_at)
    print('customer_email', email)
```

This will get the value of key if found else it will return a empty string and will not throw error